# Regular Expression for Reading Date with time in C Programme

Tags: c, regex, datetime

How to write regex expression  i am trying to get the date-time value from backlogconfig(a simple file), without affecting  the previous regex expression but I am not getting the time value from the previous one . 
The regex expression I currently use is, `%[^ \t\n\r\v\f,=]%*c %s\n`.

I want to parse this expression  `2013-08-27 00:00:00`

Comment: Why are you using regex for this?

Comment: So that i read the description from other file and use it according to my requirement

Comment: What you show is not a regular expression, it rather looks like a format string. You should show the code using it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regep that'll match time in your format !

```
([01]\d{3}|20\d{2})-(0\d|1[0-2])-([0-2]\d|3[01]) ([0-1]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d
```

It'll match any correct date, up to year 2100 (you can easily change that, of course, if your program has something to do with distant future).

Incorrect dates, for example 2001-13-55 45:79:88, are not be matched.

Comment: But i do not want to change my Regex, i am  using that one for other parsing and some how i want to use the Regex without affecting my other parsing like back.date.status=TRUE and  so  on..            This Regex gave  me the Date but not giving anyvalue when i added  the  time with date ..